# Export object options greyed out. How to export objects?

Tags: wireshark, packet

I'm following a tutorial for detecting malware with wireshark. In the tutorial he exports all http objects. When I try to export all http objects the information is greyed out. I'm on version 3.4.6. How do you get wireshark to allow you to export objects?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you stopped capturing; I was just buffled by this, then I realised... Click on the red square to stop capturing, then it should not be greyed out anymore.